# Regex to extract the main class in java source code

Tags: java, regex

I have a multi-class java file. One of those classes contains a main method (public static void main...). Example:

```
class one {...}
class two {...}
class three {
   public static void main(String[] args) {...}
}
```

I tried

```
class.*?[^.*?]*?main
```

but that matches starting at class one not class three

Comment: Given the complexity of Java syntax, a regex is not really suited for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\s*static\s*void\s*main\s*\(\s*String\s*\[\]\s*[^\)]*\)
```

if you want the name of class you can test this regex

```
class\s*([^\{]*)\{\s*.*static\s*void\s*main\s*\(\s*String\s*\[\]\s*[^\)]*\).*
```